# Как запретить запись файла другим программам?

Tags: c++, файлы

Есть файл который программа постоянно читает и пишет в него, как сделать так, чтобы пока файл занят этой программой, нельзя было бы этот файл открыть на запись  из другой программы.

Comment: А разве винда не закрывает доступ к данному файлу по умолчанию?

Comment: Обычно надо потрудиться, чтобы это было не так... :)

Comment: В заголовке про запрет чтения, в тексте - про запрет записи. Вы уж определитесь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы хотите, организуется по умолчанию и так. Но если вы уж очень хотите явно указать это - то можно, например, открывать файл с помощью функции [`_fsopen`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f30b0db.aspx) (по крайней мере в Windows) с флагом `_SH_DENYRW` в качестве третьего параметра.

Answer (score 2):

В общем случае никак. Можно почитать тут https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking или более куций вариант, но по-русски [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Блокировка_файла](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0)

В кратце, под виндой нужно использовать `CreateFile` с правильными флагами (см. MSDN), по linux есть только джентельмеское соглашение `flock`, которое тоже работает не везде и не всегда. Если обе программы твои, то можно использовать именованный мьютекс.

Comment: Это вы немного не о том...

Comment: FILE_SHARE_READ вод виндой и файл можно будет читать из другого процесса. А если не ставить никакие флаги - файл будет экслюзивно открыт.